# Arangodb UPDATE 2 different documents in 1 AQL

Tags: arangodb

How can we do it since

```
For v in relation

UPDATE { _key: v._from,"foo": false } IN A
UPDATE { _key: v._to,"foo": false } IN A
```

would return error of reading modified data. What is the correct way of doing this in AQL?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Operations/Update.html#update)

> Only a single UPDATE statement per collection is allowed per AQL query